# AngularJS hashing bundles to prevent caching

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have an AngularJS application and after every update I've got caching issues. So my idea was to add versioning or hashing to the bundles.

I'd read about ng build -prod but that ain't working (maybe because it only works with Angular?). Another options is maybe to use gulp to hash the bundles. Well this works but I don't know how to get these hashed files in the index.html.

I couldn't find a simple solution for it so hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed, you can't use Angular CLI (`ng` commands) with AngularJS.
How do you build your app and bundle your scritps?

Comment: I'm using ng build

Comment: Which Angular version are you using ? AngularJS (1.x) or Angular (2+)

Comment: AngularJS (1.x)

Comment: Wait, it's possible to build an AngularJS app with Angular CLI ?

Comment: Actually, sorry for not mention it before but it's a hybrid app, I'm using angular version 1.x for my components and using @angular 4.x and @angular/cli 1.x. I'm using downgradeNg2Component for my components

Comment: Hmmmm ok! Anyway, did you tried `ng build --prod`?

Comment: Wow, I tried ng build -prod but that didn't work. This was working fine :) Thnx @zoo

Comment: No problem :) Do you agree if I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes I will but I got only one problem when I want to run my project I get the error Uncaught Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.